# Atom is giving me the error Cannot find module 'editorconfig'

Tags: html, atom-editor

Whenever I try to save a .html file, the Atom text editor gives me the error Cannot find module 'editorconfig', I installed the EditorConfig package a long time before I started getting the error. How can I fix this so I can save my code files?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that an uninstall / reinstall solves the problem (3 days ago here : https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify/issues/2245)